# Change TextBox.Text on parent container's visibility change using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, visibility

I am building a LOB application with WPF and MVVM. When the user needs to insert client details he can do so from a number of windows (which are user controls with the visibility property set through binding, so he can see only one at a time).

The problem is that all TextBox controls keep their text values between visibility changes (collapsed <-> visible) and I want to reset them.
Creating a trigger in the textbox style does not work (but no errors or anything).

How should I do it to keep in relation with the MVVM pattern ?

I am thinking of using ObjectDataProvider to call a method that is using reflection and set each TextBox.Text value. This objectdataprovider would be set with triggers in the StackPanel (the container) style.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you're trying to achieve is a wizard. When the user clicks Next, the current user control is hidden and the next user control is revealed.

Since you are doing MVVM, I would expect each `TextBox.Text` to be bound to a property on the view model. If this is true, then you shouldn't need to use triggers. All you should do is set each property to an empty string just prior to setting the visibility of the user control to `Visible`.

For example, if the user click Next, and the next screen to be shown is `Screen3`, then you should set all the properties on `Screen3ViewModel` that are used to populate the text fields (such as `Name`, `Address`, `Occupation`) to empty strings.

Your text boxes should look something like this:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Name} />
<TextBox Text={Binding Address} />
<TextBox Text={Binding Occupation} />
```

In other words, do everything through code, not markup.

Note that you will need to make sure that your view models implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the binding engine knows to update the text fields when you change the properties in the view model.

Comment: It is not a wizard. I just use different user controls to insert values. But the functionality is the same as you have described it. The logic for the visibility of user controls is on a different viewmodel so I will still have to use reflection. I will try both methods and see what works with less code. Thanks.

Comment: I have ended up using a button to explicitly reset the fields. Setting values for the view model's properties did not work even though everything was set correctly.